# Identify short sequences of matches between 2 strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-matching

I have the following code:

```
for k, (j,k) in enumerate (zip(line1_u,line2_u_rev_comp)):
    if j==k:
        Match1+=1 
    if j== 'N' or k == 'N':
        Unknown1+=1
    if j != k:
        Different1+=1
```

This takes 2 lines (line1_u and line2_u_rev_comp) and compares them character by character to identify if they match, have an N which places it in the unknown category or are different. What I want is as well as tallying up each of these is to identify if 10 characters or more in a row match. How could this be done? Explanation of code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby

def class_chars(chrs):
    if 'N' in chrs:
        return 'unknown'
    elif chrs[0] == chrs[1]:
        return 'match'
    else:
        return 'not_match'

s1 = 'aaaaaaaaaaN123bbbbbbbbbbQccc'
s2 = 'aaaaaaaaaaN456bbbbbbbbbbPccc'
n = 0
consec_matches = []
chars = defaultdict(int)

for k, group in groupby(zip(s1, s2), class_chars):
    elems = len(list(group))
    chars[k] += elems
    if k == 'match':
        consec_matches.append((n, n+elems-1))
    n += elems

print chars
print consec_matches
print [x for x in consec_matches if x[1]-x[0] >= 9]
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'not_match': 4, 'unknown': 1, 'match': 23})
[(0, 9), (14, 23), (25, 27)]
[(0, 9), (14, 23)]
```

Comment: Thats a very good point about the 'N' issue I hadn't thought about yet, thanks for picking that up. With this code is there anyway to make it yet more complex by informing me about the location of the 10+ matches within the sequences? Only just realised that this would be of added benefit.

Comment: @Tom I've updated my answer. I've stored all consecutive matches in a list - to get all those that are of length > 10, just use `filter` or a list comprehension like I've did in the code. I also realized that you want to "stop" the chain of consecutive matches if there is a `'N'`, so I fixed that as well.

Comment: With N what I want is for those pairs to be ignored  as in this dataset N is an error so cannot be used but the matching should continue until there are no more pairs. Also which part stops the code if there is an 'N'? The rest of it seems perfect with the positional data.

Comment: @Tom I meant that, given the two strings: `s1='aaaNaaa'` and `s2='aaaNaaa'`, the output should be two groups of consecutive matches, from index 0-2 and 4-6, not one match from index 0-6 (including the `N`s). Is that the behaviour you expect? If so, the code should do as you want.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, thats totally correct. Again thank you for solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the difflib module in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html. Use `find_longest_match` to find the longest common subsequence.