# If string is not correct, go back to previous command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I currently have my code going line by line through a file and cutting a character from the lines.

I want to have it so that after cutting the character of the line it  attempts to merge the 2 lines (already written and works), if the merging doesnt work it should return to cutting another character and merge again and continue this loop until they do merge or it completes this attempt 100 times.

Is there anyway I can do this? I thought a for loop might work but unsure how to use it in this way. I am currently using the lines of code below to iteratively go through each file line by line so I was wondering would something similar work?

```
        line2_u_rev_comp = [tbl[k] for k in line2_u.strip()[::-1]]
        verboseprint (line2_u_rev_comp)
        line2_u_rev_comp_join = ''.join(line2_u_rev_comp)
        verboseprint (line2_u_rev_comp_join)
        verboseprint ("Line2 has been reverse complemented to match line1")
```

The error that occurs at the moment is:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Join.py", line 77, in <module>
    line2_u_rev_comp = [tbl[k] for k in line2_u.strip()[::-1]]
KeyError: '2'
```

Comment: What do you mean by *merging*? Why wouldn't it work? Where is the code that does this *cutting*?

Comment: The code cutts at the start of 1 and the end of another then looks for similarity between the 2 and merges if the similarity is greater than 10 characters long, if not thats when I want it to attempt cutting again

Comment: Looks good so far then, just implement the answers you were given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548091/identify-short-sequences-of-matches-between-2-strings inside your for loop to decide if they "merge" or not

Comment: I already have with that code entered so they can merge or not but how will it know to go back to the cutting part if merging doesnt occur? Surely it would go onto the next line as it would have finished my code for that line so can I say "if not merged return to line 37" or something along those lines?

Comment: Don't think "going back" - think don't "move forward" until you're happy... the `for` block you have there will only move to the next pair of lines once the inside block is fully complete... just make sure you don't leave it until you've tried what you want first

Comment: Can you put a for loop in a for loop then so for each line iteratively it will cut and merge, if not it will attempt again etc ?

Comment: For some reason doing this has introduced a Keyerror '2' in the line         line2_u_rev_comp = [tbl[k] for k in line2_u.strip()[::-1]] what does this error mean? tbl in this line is a dictonary.

Comment: my crystal ball is failing me at the moment :) [edit] your question to include all the things you've tried and the new code (maybe even thought about) so far and then it might become a solveable question

Comment: don't forget to put the *full traceback* - not just the last two lines of it - otherwise anyone willing to help has to search the code for the exact line causing the error...

Comment: `Python raises a KeyError whenever a dict() object is requested (using the format a = adict[key]) and the key is not in the dictionary.` So, you have a character '2' in the line and that's clearly not in the dictionary... what that means regarding what you're trying to do - no idea... but that's what the error means... (btw - it's fairly googleable!)

Comment: But the only two '2' in the line refer to the line taken from the file on which the dictonary is beig used on

Comment: then handle it appropriately? Remove it maybe? I don't know your data... these are things you can work through yourself... You're asking Python to look at each character in the line and look it up in your dictionary... you don't have a value for `2` so it complains... how you fix having `2` there or not is up to you...